# Липкий блок на JS проблема

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток.
Хочу прикрутить следующий скрипт для фиксации блоков

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var sb_m = 80; /* отступ сверху и снизу */
var mb = 300; /* высота подвала с запасом */
var st = $(window).scrollTop();
var sb = $(".loginform");
var sbi = $(".loginform #loginform");
var sb_ot = sb.offset().top;
var sbi_ot = sbi.offset().top;
var sb_h = sb.height();

if(sb_h + $(document).scrollTop() + sb_m + mb < $(document).height()) {
    if(st > sb_ot) {
        var h = Math.round(st - sb_ot) + sb_m;
        sb.css({"paddingTop" : h});
    }
    else {
        sb.css({"paddingTop" : 0});
    }
}
```

});

[На голом html работает прекрасно](https://jsfiddle.net/trauka/nqu6jce4/11/)

Начинаю прикручивать на живой сайт (wordpress) - появляется какой-то бесконечный скрол.

[ссылка на страницу со скриптом](http://u1454804.isp.regruhosting.ru/)

Мне кажется что что-то со стилями я упускаю.

Обратила внимание, что такой "бесконечный скрол" появляется если добавить какой нибудь элемент в подвал,

в данном случае добавлены текстовые виджеты.

Пожалуйста подскажите что я не так сделала?

Comment: я сейчас зашел на сайт и скролл работает, полностью футер я вижу, не могу понять вашу проблему

Answer (score 1):

Это вкорне неправильное решение. Увеличивая "paddingTop" вы увеличиваете высоту документа создавая бесконечный скролл. Лучше использовать css, например position: fixed.